# Avoiding repetition

Tags: writing-style, repetition

The original sentence is :

> Here the plus and minus signs refer to the potential with lower right well  and to the potential with lower left well, respectively.

How should I avoid repeating the part **the potential with lower**?

Comment: Writing advice and rephrasing suggestions are OT. Could also be POB.

Comment: Since you identified the specific issue, this possibly falls under ELU's *Usage* portion. In any case, here are 2 suggestions: "Here the plus and minus signs refer to the potentials with lower *right and left* wells, respectively." or "Here the plus (respectively, minus) sign refers to the potential with lower right (left) well."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here the plus and minus signs refer to the potential with lower right well and to **the one** with lower left well, respectively.

I'm not sure we can do any better. Why does your title contain *auxiliaries*, by the way ? I fail to see how auxiliaries could come in handy here.